# Ajax in jQuery with ASP.NET - return string

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to write a simple ajax call with jQuery in ASP.NET.

Here is the Ajax call in JavaScript file:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: "AjaxCall.aspx/GetSquare",
            dataType: "text",

            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },

            error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
        });
```

And here is the web method in .aspx file:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetSquare()
    {
        return "OK";
    }
```

And this is what I get in alert:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
<head><title>    
</title></head>    
<body>    
    <form method="post" action="GetSquare" id="form1">    
<div class="aspNetHidden">   
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZLfZC2ZpNR/9g+3q7Z3ARCxIRMMXrN2MoePSYHvaiYH3" /> 
</div>
    <div>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why returned value was whole html markup instead of "OK"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change datatype, try this

```
dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 2):

you can have a look at the following

// Code behind method declared static

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSquare()
{
    return "OK";
}
```

your button whose click this has to be done

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Chnageurl" onclick="ajaxcall()" />
```

script for this

```
<script type="text/jscript">

    function ajaxcall(e) {        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetSquare",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },

            error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: the alert(data.d) showed my return value, but alert(data) doesnt. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you to check out below article and change your code accordingly:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

It could be the reason, you might be missing [web.config](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx) entry.